# AWS Switch Region from East1 to West2

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have an application that uses Amazon Web Services. We have designed it such that images and videos (S3) are sent to East1 region, while images and videos' metadata (DynamoDB) are sent to West2 region.
But we can't get it to switch from using the east1 to west2.

When we initialized our AWS, we have this:

```
self.provider = [AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider credentialsWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                               accountId:AWS_ACCOUNT_ID
                                                          identityPoolId:COGNITO_POOL_ID
                                                           unauthRoleArn:COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH
                                                             authRoleArn:COGNITO_ROLE_AUTH];
self.east1Configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                         credentialsProvider:self.provider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = self.east1Configuration;


self.west2Configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest2
                                                        credentialsProvider:self.provider];
```

Now when we want to send video and image metadata, we also tried to set the serviceConfiguration to west:

```
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = self.west2Configuration;
```

But it's not working. It won't switch to west2.
I hope I make sense, Thank you.

Comment: When do you create your connection to AWS in the above sequence?

Comment: We have a manager class with initializeAWS function. we call the initializeAWS function. applicationDidFinishLaunching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultServiceConfiguration` can only be set once (only the first configuration assigned will be valid). In order to switch between configurations, you need to call `- initWithConfiguration:` on `AWSS3` and `AWSDynamoDB` instead of `+ defaultS3` and `+ defaultDynamoDB`.

Please note that when you use `- initWithConfiguration:`, you need to retain a strong reference to the service client object. For `+ defaultS3` and `+ defaultDynamoDB`, the SDK maintains the strong references (these are singleton methods). Just like you are making configuration objects `@property`, you can make the service client `@property` as well.

Comment: Thank you Matsuda-san. Our team has decided to just do dynamoDB-related stuff in our back-end. But I do get your point here, this will still be very useful in our other future projects.

Comment: `initWithConfiguration` is now deprecated. Use `registerS3WithConfiguration` to initialize and `S3ForKey` to access. No need to keep a reference.