# How to Change DynamoDB Region

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How do I change DynamoDB Region Programtically? I have set to USEast but i want to later switch it to US west I know there is another answer on Stack Overflow but that answer is deprecated. This was the answer on stack: [AWS Switch Region from East1 to West2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350068/aws-switch-region-from-east1-to-west2) The documentation is not clear on this one.

Comment: Please consider the following improvements: link the answer to make it obvious which you are talking about, add a link to the documentation and show why the documentation is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

options are:

1. using [Cross-Region Replication Using DynamoDB Streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.CrossRegionRepl.html) (copy your data to other regions)
2. migrate your data from one region to other region (using [aws data pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/))

Comment: I don't think first solution will work. An existing table cannot be upgraded to a Global table https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/globaltables_HowItWorks.html

Answer (score 0):

I've written a script to do this for large DynamoDB tables that handles pagination.

https://gist.github.com/davoscollective/15e15ec2b2ec368f6cc71509c9693d34

It's based on another script that doesn't have pagination, but does create the table for you. see https://gist.github.com/Dineshkarthik/d0944c45b06726a327a9536a33dabdd2 for that.

Essentially, you can't just change the region of the table. You have to create the same named table in the new region, and copy the data over. I've read that old AWS article about using data pipeline, however no such button exists in the AWS console anymore. DynamoDB Streams is a good option but requires you to create global (more expensive) table up front, which is not helpful when all you want to do is migrate regions with an already existing table full of data.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and all the solutions I found on StackOverflow were outdated or way more complicated than necessary. After trying a couple propositions, I ended up writing a NodeJS script to move the data over. Maybe that could work for you? If you want to try, I documented my approach on my blog [here](https://tvernon.tech/blog/move-dynamodb-data-between-regions).